# Http connection refused

Tags: 16.04, server

I run on the ubuntu server a http server that listen on the port 8080
[image]

When I try to request the http server via curl:

```
Failed to connect to 122.22.22.22 port 8080: Connection refused
```

Do I miss some configuration?

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: It is not clear details, but you decided to provide "lsb_release -a" somewhy :) What is the output of "netstat -a"? And another question why you connect to 122.22.22.22 when ***LESTINING ON LOCALHOST***?

Comment: Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals). Paste the text directly to your question and apply code formatting (the `{}` icon).

Comment: can you please add the outputs of `uname -a` and `ufw status`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP server listens only on localhost (127.0.0.1), so try

```
curl http://localhost:8080
```

If you want the server to [listen on all your IPv4 addresses](https://www.howtogeek.com/225487/what-is-the-difference-between-127.0.0.1-and-0.0.0.0/), start the server with `0.0.0.0:8080`